# Italic journal title Word bibliography

Tags: xslt, ms-word

For a paper I'm writing in medicine (not to be published, just for my education) in Microsoft Office 2010 Professional Plus, Word, I need to use Vancouver style references.

I've found a style online (xsl) and formatted it to the needs of our faculty:
`Autors A. Title. Journal Title. YEAR;v(n):p.`

However, I can't seem to get the journal title in *italics*. Is there a way I can edit "`{%JournalName%. }`" to get it in italics font?

Thanks!

M

`<source type="JournalArticle">
        <column id="1">
          <halign>right</halign>
          <valign>top</valign>
          <format>{%RefOrder%.}</format>
        </column>
        <column id="2">
          <halign>left</halign>
          <valign>top</valign>
          <format>{%Author:1%. }{%Title%. }{%JournalName%. }{%Year%{ %Month:s%{ %Day%}}};{%Volume%}{(%Issue%)}{:%Pages::%}.</format>
        </column>
        <sortkey></sortkey>
      </source>`

Comment: What transformation did you apply to what input data and what is the intended output format? Show some code?

Comment: I basically don't have any idea ... Just took an xsl file from the internet, deleted some spaces and changed curved to square brackets ...

I've copied the code for "JournalArticle" in the original message.

Comment: What XSLT? What input data?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I absolutely have no idea what you mean. I was just lucky enough to get it to work so far, but I'm not experienced in whatever you might mean whatsoever ... (see code in original post)

Comment: Where's the XSLT code you found, and how did you get it to work?

Comment: I've uploaded the file here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00319171265895643004

There were some spaces between the different attributes (the year and volume are supposed to be separeted by a ; only, not ; and a space, so I removed the space in wordpad), so I removed these spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by replacing `{%JournalName%. }` by `{&lt;i&gt;%JournalName%&lt;/i&gt;. }`